# Is there a way to find location of the top n elements in a group by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

Need to extract attribute of top n elements of a pandas dataframe

input data is like below

```
    KEY variable    value
0   1   A   0.476970
101 1   B   0.513333
202 1   C   0.376970
203 2   B   0.5667
101 2   A   0.513333
202 2   C   0.376970
```

...

i need out put of top two as this

```
KEY variable    value
1   A   0.476970
1   B   0.513333
2   B   0.5667
2   A   0.513333
...
```

the code i tried is as follows

```
test=pred_melt.groupby(['KEY'])['value'].nlargest(2)
```

this gives me

```
KEY     
1          101    0.513333
           0      0.476970
...
Name: value, Length: 198, dtype: float64
```

idea was to join with original with the index (101,0 etc) to add the variable column but cannot get the index out of get the desired output as above.
not the group by column is key and not the variable.

Comment: What is meant by "top"? In the sample output you provided, values are not sorted in any order.

Comment: by top i mean largest 2 by value. in the example , .51 and .47 are the biggest values for key =1

Comment: Okay. So you want the index of `test`? If that is the case, you can use `test.index`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Supratim, yes index but i added the rest of details that i had to workout. please comment if you feel needed.

```
test=pred_melt.groupby(['KEY'])['value'].nlargest(2)
test.index
```

returns MultiIndex
as per 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html
the structure is

```
 MultiIndex(levels=[...], [...]],
            codes=[[...], [..]],
            names=[...])
```

I am interested in

```
test.index.levels[1]
```

which is giving  me the second column of this

```
KEY     
1          101    0.513333
           0      0.476970
...
Name: value, Length: 198, dtype: float64
```

as 0,101 etc which can use to get the records from pred_melt

```
    KEY variable    value
0   1   A   0.476970
101 1   B   0.513333
202 1   C   0.376970
203 2   B   0.5667
101 2   A   0.513333
202 2   C   0.376970
```

as

```
pred_melt.iloc[test.index.levels[1]]
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks @P RAY for adding the rest of the solution!